# Pass DateTime milisecons size for MySQL "DATETIME(3)" in Laravel Migration

Tags: mysql, laravel, migration

I need to use MySQL Datetime with miliseconds, in documentation they told us to use `DATETIME(3)`

It's possible to do this with Laravel Migrations?

I tried `$table->dateTime('datetime', 3);` with no success

Comment: You probably have to implement this yourself, see https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/3506